# How do I test Persistent Memory using Xcode's iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, persistence

I have an NSMutableArray of custom objects saved to persistent memory like so:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:[PlayerMenuController savedPlayers] toFile:@"/Users/Dec/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/9BC31B2A-/savedPlayers"];
}
```

Which are loaded then tested as seen below:

```
NSMutableArray *loadedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"/Users/Dec/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/9BC31B2A-/savedPlayers"];
if (loadedArray != nil)
{
    [[PlayerMenuController savedPlayers] setArray:loadedArray];
}


for (int i = 0; i < [[PlayerMenuController savedPlayers] count]; i++)
{
    Player *p = [[PlayerMenuController savedPlayers] objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@ %u",[p getName],[p getSaveId]);
}
NSLog(@"%u",[[PlayerMenuController savedPlayers] count]);
```

To test this I open my app, save a few objects in to the array, minimise the app then close the application via the task manager/double clicking home. When I open my app again it appears the debugger as detached, none of my break points or NSLogs are called.

How do I go about debugging my app over multiple uses so i can test my apps ability to save and load data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the app in debug mode again via XCode. Don't run it by clicking on the app icon on the simulator. If you don't change the code, it won't rebuild. You'll have the same bundle and settings.

Also, press the Stop button in XCode to stop the app rather than shutting it down in the simulator.

Comment: Doing this does not call applicationDidEnterBackground.

Comment: Simply press the home button to trigger `applicationDidEnterBackground`. Use Stop button over double-tap home button and closing app.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the simulators "content" on:

`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/`

Then you will have to guess your apps directory by going into each one of them. Then look under the `Documents` folder. Your plist should be there.